# How to compare XML files using PowerShell while ignoring certain tags?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm using PowerShell in order to compare two different xml files with the following code:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\newtask3.xml | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' })(Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\newtask4.xml | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' })
```

The first XML file:

```
<html>a
    <ID>GT-ANI-2016-05-02T21:01Z</ID>
    <CreationDate>2016-05-02T21:01:40</CreationDate>
    <Total> 5000 </Total>
    <type>ANI</type>
</html>
```

The second XML file:

```
<html>a
    <ID>GT-ANI-2016-05-03T21:06Z</ID>
    <CreationDate>2016-05-03T21:06:40</CreationDate>
    <Total> 5000 </Total>
    <type>ANI</type>
</html>
```

My question is: How can I make sure that the PowerShell script ignores the unique fields in `<ID>`, `<CreationDate>` when comparing the two xml files from above?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing parts. "the unique fields in ?", "the duplicate value of ?". Could be automatically being removed. Are you asking for this specific xml or xmls in general? What's the outcome you're after? As per BenH's reply you can import as `[xml]` which gives you access to properties (and values). Happy to help, am just unsure what the aim is.

Comment: Hi i have alted my question a bit in the hope that its more cleare wat i mean. I also removed the part of dulplicate values and instead just want to know how i can Ensure that the compare ingnore certain tags. These tags are the same between the two xml files that i compare but can be difrent if i compare aonther xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. I've tried to be explicit in breaking down how to handle `xml`/`html`, properties and built-in/manual comparison in PowerShell.

```
# Import files, casting as xml type.
[xml]$html1 = Get-Content -Path .\1.xml
[xml]$html2 = Get-Content -Path .\2.xml

# Get the members of the html 1's properties where membertype is properties (i.e. the tags)
# See bottom comment for getting tags from both documents
$htmlTags  = ($html1.html | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.membertype -eq "Property"}).Name

# Put the tags you would like to ignore in an array
$ignoreTheseTags = @("type","ID")

#Loop over the tags, ignoring the ones that you have put in the array
foreach ($tag in $htmlTags | Where-Object {$_ -notin $ignoreTheseTags}){

    # Get the values in this tag.
    $value1 = $html1.html.$tag
    $value2 = $html2.html.$tag

    # You can test to see if the tag is in file 2
    # Continue skips to next tag as Compare-Object will return an error if one of the objects is null
    if($value2 -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Tag $tag is not in html 2`n"
        continue
    }

    # PowerShell built-in comparison operator
    Compare-Object  $value1 $value2

    # Manual case-sensitive value comparison. You can do whatever you want inside the loop
    if($value1 -cne $value2){
        Write-Host "Tag $tag is not equal."
        Write-Host "First file value:  $value1"
        Write-Host "Second file value: $value2`n"
    }

}

<#
#Getting tags from both html documents
$htmlTags  = ($html1.html | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.membertype -eq "Property"})
$htmlTags += ($html2.html | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.membertype -eq "Property"})

$htmlTags = ($htmlTags | Select-Object Name -Unique).Name
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there isn't an easy way to do this. You could import the xml documents in as variables, then find the shared properties and filtering out the ones that are arrays. Then do a compare using that filtered list of properties.

```
[xml]$XmlDocument1 = Get-Content -Path C:\example1.xml
[xml]$XmlDocument2 = Get-Content -Path C:\example2.xml
$xml1props = ($XmlDocument1.html | gm | ? {$_.membertype -eq "Property"  -AND ($_.definition.split(" "))[0] -eq "string"}).name
$xml2props = ($XmlDocument2.html | gm | ? {$_.membertype -eq "Property"  -AND ($_.definition.split(" "))[0] -eq "string"}).name
$sharedprops = (Compare-Object $xml1props $xml2props -IncludeEqual | ? {$_.sideindicator -eq "=="}).inputobject
compare-object $XmlDocument1.html $XmlDocument2.html -Property $sharedprops
```